# Automatically pickup uploaded text file from Blob Storage and import data to Azure SQL

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-logic-apps, azure-blob-storage

I have a Blob Storage, and an Azure SQL DB.

When I upload a text file to my Blob Storage, says users.txt which contains list of users I need to import to User table in my SQL DB.

Is there a way that whenever a file arrive to Blob Storage, it will trigger an event. That event will trigger another event to import data to SQL DB(I don't know, but may be an Azure function, Logic App...). Therefore I don't need to write any code. Is that possible? If so, could you please let me know step by step how to do it?

Any help would be highly appreciated!.

Thanks!.

Answer (score 1):

Teka a look at [Azure Blob storage trigger for Azure Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob-trigger?tabs=csharp), which describes how you can use a "blob added" event to trigger an Azure Function. You can do something like below.

```
[FunctionName("SaveTextBlobToDb")]
public static void Run(
    [BlobTrigger("container-with-text-files/{name}", Connection = "StorageConnectionAppSetting")] Stream streamWithTextFile)
{
    // your logic for handling new blob (streamWithTextFile)
}
```

In the implementation, you can save the blob content to your SQL database. If you want to make sure that the blob is not lost due to any transient errors (like issues with db connectivity), you can first put the info about new blob to an Azure storage queue, and then have a separate Azure Function to take each blob-info from the queue and transfer the content to the database.

Comment: Though correct, this involves coding and the OP specifically asked for a solution that involves no coding

Answer (score 1):

One solution that comes to mind, other than the options you already know, is [Azure Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/introduction). It is a kind of [ETL tool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extract,_transform,_load) for the cloud. It allows you to set up pipelines for data processing with defined inputs and outputs. In your scenario the input would be a blob and the output would be a Sql Server database record.

You can trigger the pipeline to be executed in the event a new blob is added. The docs even have an example showing just that, you can find it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/how-to-create-event-trigger).

In your case you can probably use the [Copy Activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-overview) to copy the data from the blob to sql server. A tutorial titled "Copy data from Azure Blob storage to a SQL Database by using the Copy Data tool" is found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/tutorial-copy-data-tool)

An Azure Function will do the job as well but will involve coding. A Logic App is also a good option.

Answer (score 0):

You answered your question...azure function or logic app. You can declaratively bind to your blob within an azure function, you can use the blob trigger on a logic app as well. Someone suggested data factory (this would necessarily be the most expensive option).